# How to get users of a specefic role in Yii2 and DbManager?

Tags: php, yii, yii2, rbac

How to get users of a specefic role in Yii2 and DbManager in RBAC?

Please introduce some API for user management and role management.

I searched and read [Yii2 guide](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-index.html) but I didn't find any solution.

Comment: The rbac\managerInterface does not provide an API for this. You will have to write your own, if you are using DbManager for your RBAC it is fairly straight forward, you can simply write a DB query. If you are using the PhpManager then it is little more complex as the filemanger stores the data in array like [user][role] so you will have to transpose the array first to get the data, or iterate over all users.

Comment: Thanks man. I wrote a function based on your guide.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I used @Manquer guide and wrote this function:

```
public static function getRoleUsers($role_name)
    {
        $connection = \Yii::$app->db;
        $connection->open();

        $command = $connection->createCommand(
            "SELECT * FROM auth_assignment INNER JOIN user ON auth_assignment.user_id = user.id " .
            "WHERE auth_assignment.item_name = '" . $role_name . "';");

        $users = $command->queryAll();
        $connection->close();

        return $users;
    }
```

Maybe useful for someone.

Answer (score 9):

Since Yii version 2.0.7, `DbManager` and `ManagerInterface` which it implements have [`getUserIdsByRole($roleName)`](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-rbac-managerinterface.html#getUserIdsByRole()-detail) which does what you want without custom code.

Comment: With this block of code you can retrive user model by role:
$operatoriIds = Yii::$app->authManager->getUserIdsByRole('operator');
$operators = User::find()->where(['id' => $operatoriIds])->all();

Comment: This is a very clean solution and it worked for me.

Answer (score 5):

I wrote this function which can be added to an User class.

```
 /**
 * Finds all users by assignment role
 *
 * @param  \yii\rbac\Role $role
 * @return static|null
 */
public static function findByRole($role)
{
    return static::find()
        ->join('LEFT JOIN','auth_assignment','auth_assignment.user_id = id')
        ->where(['auth_assignment.item_name' => $role->name])
        ->all();
}
```

Comment: By using `LEFT JOIN` you will also get users that don't have any role associated with them.