# To Get Role Of A User - Yii2

Tags: php, yii2, yii2-advanced-app, yii2-basic-app, yii2-user-roles

I was searching for user role for logged in user, I'm not getting how to print user role name. I Tried this:

```
$Role = Yii::$app->authManager->getRolesByUser(Yii::$app->user->getId());
```

When, I did `print_r($Role)`; I got this :

```
Array ( [superadmin] => yii\rbac\Role Object ( [type] => 1 [name] => superadmin [description] => Super admin can do any operation in the application [ruleName] => [data] => [createdAt] => [updatedAt] => ) )
```

I was looking to get particular role name, but i was unable to access

```
Array ( [superadmin] => yii\rbac\Role Object ........)
           ^ unable to access this name.
```

When typing `print_r($Role[0]->name);` I'm getting error like

> PHP Notice – yii\base\ErrorException
>
> Undefined offset: 0

And, If I do like this way (means, manually passing `$rolename` to array index) It is working.

```
$roleName = 'superadmin';

print_r($Role[$roleName]->name);
```

Why this requirement came to me, because for logged in user It's Ok. But, if i want to know other user role name, then I need that index name to pass here `$Role[$roleName]->name`

Please help me to access this 'superadmin'. I'm not getting how to get index name of it.

```
Array ( [superadmin] => yii\rbac\Role Object
               ^ unable to access this name.
```

I also checked [Get User Role](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25247675/how-to-get-user-role-in-yii2)  & [Specific Role Of User](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25247774/how-to-get-users-of-a-specefic-role-in-yii2-and-dbmanager)

Comment: U can use for this array_shift e.g: if(is_array($Role))array_shift($Role)->name; i't only get first element of this array

Comment: Yeah. It's Correct @NuriddinRashidov. You are my saviour since so many days. Glad to have you in my list. Can you please write this as answer.

Comment: Firstly @Nana  thank you for your attention to my comment. I wrote my answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So you can use  for this [array_shift](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-shift.php). It's return first element of array E.g:

```
if(is_array($Role))array_shift($Role)->name;
```

Comment: Thanks. Nuriddin.  :)

Comment: Not at all my friend.

Comment: `Yii::$app->authManager->getRolesByUser()` always returns array, so check for `is_array` is redundant. `$role` is not inappropriate name, because this array can contain more than one role, it's better to name it `$roles`. Calling `name` from `array_shift` lacks code highlighting in IDE. Code is not `PSR-2` compatible (and Yii2 follows it and recommends to follow it in your own code).

Answer (score 7):

User can have multiple roles, and in `authManager` there is no method for getting just one role for user.

You can use this code in case of one role (I'd recommend to place it in a `User` model to keep code cleaner):

```
/**
 * Returns user role name according to RBAC
 * @return string
 */
public function getRoleName()
{
    $roles = Yii::$app->authManager->getRolesByUser($this->id);
    if (!$roles) {
        return null;
    }

    reset($roles);
    /* @var $role \yii\rbac\Role */
    $role = current($roles);

    return $role->name;
}
```

No need to check for array because `getRolesByUser` already returns an array.

Alternatively you can use `array_shift` as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1921421/get-the-first-element-of-an-array) or return a key of array element because it's indexed by names (described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1028668/get-first-key-in-a-possibly-associative-array)).

Because of such indexation, you can't get `0` element of an array (it simply don't exist). That's why you got `Undefined offset: 0` exception.

Example of usage in view:

```
<?php if (!Yii::$app->user->isGuest) { ?>
    <div class="user-role"><?= Yii::$app->user->identity->getRoleName() ?></div>
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: Hi Mr Arogachev : Your code working perfectly. Thanks a lot. I was using array_shift as it is suggested by Mr @Nuriddin. But, I will use this too. Thanks :)

Comment: @NanaPartykar `array_shift` works too, please read my other remarks and explanation.

Answer (score 1):

Your array doesn't have the `0` index. As the [documentation](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-rbac-managerinterface.html#getRolesByUser%28%29-detail) says the array is indexed by the role names.

So, if you have 100% all users will always have only one role. You could call it like this:

```
print_r(reset($Role));
```

But if the user can have multiple roles, you can use a loop for that:

```
foreach ($Role as $each) {
    print_r($each);
}
```

Comment: User has one role only. And, when i do `print_r(reset($Role));` I get `yii\rbac\Role Object ( [type] => 1 [name] => superadmin [description] => Super admin can do any operation in the application [ruleName] => [data] => [createdAt] => [updatedAt] => ) `. And, when i do like `print_r(reset($Role['name']));` or `print_r(reset($Role->name));` . I get error like **Attempt to modify property of non-object** Please suggest me how to take `name`. Thanks

Comment: Yup you used wrongly. Since `reset` was returning your object, it was just a matter of calling any attribute of it AFTER the reset. It would be `print_r(reset($Role)->name)`. Too bad you din't noticed (or even asked me) that before, i was the first to answer T-T

Comment: Sorry Mr @Clyff. Please Don't Mind. Thanks For Your Effort. I'm Embarassaed.

Comment: Hahaha ok nevermind, it happens. But i would recommend you use my suggestion in your project, is the fastest / cleanest.

Answer (score 1):

```
$getRolesByUser = Yii::$app->authManager->getRolesByUser(Yii::$app->user->getId());

$Role = array_keys($getRolesByUser)[0];
```

Answer (score 1):

in my opinion the best way is:

```
if (array_key_exists('Admin', \Yii::$app->authManager->getRolesByUser(Yii::$app->user->id))) { ... }
```

PS the above for the Role "Admin".